# jshint error when pass wp_localize_script() object to js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to click on a button and get a response.

**Here is the button**

```
$output .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
    $label = __( 'More Stories', 'everstrap' );
    $output .= "<button type='buttn' class='button_two load-more-btn'>{$label}</button>";
$output .= '</div>';
```

**How I passing `ajaxob` Object:**

```
$script_data_array = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'load_more_posts' ),
);
wp_localize_script( 'everstrap-scripts', 'ajaxobj', $script_data_array );
```

**Now, the JS file code is bellow:**

```
window.EStrap = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var app = {
        init: function () {
            console.log('Working');
            $(window).on('scroll', app.handleSticky);
            $('.hamburger-btn').on('click', app.toggleNavDrawer);
            $('.nav-drawer-close').on('click', app.closeNavDrawer);
            $('.load-more-btn').on('click', app.loadMoreStories);
        },
        loadMoreStories:function(){
            var page = 2;
            var data = {
                'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
                'page': page,
                'security': ajaxobj.security
            };   
            $.post(ajaxobj.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                if($.trim(response) !== '') {
                    $('.load-more-stories').append(response);
                    page++;
                } else {
                    $('.load-more-btn').hide();
                }
            });
        },
        handleSticky:function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
                $('#main-nav').addClass('sticky-header');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
                $('#main-nav').removeClass('sticky-header');
            }
        },
        toggleNavDrawer:function () {
            var $nav_drawer = $('#nav-drawer');
            $nav_drawer.toggleClass('open');
        },
        closeNavDrawer:function () {
            var $nav_drawer = $('#nav-drawer');
            $nav_drawer.removeClass('open');
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(app.init);
    return app;
})(window, document, jQuery);
```

Now when I do save changes I saw following error from jshint

> assets/js/scripts.js
>        17 |                'security': ajaxobj.security
>                                        ^ 'ajaxobj' is not defined.
>        19 |            $.post(ajaxobj.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
>                               ^ 'ajaxobj' is not defined.

Why `ajaxobj` is not accessible here and how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Please check wp_enqueue_script('everstrap-scripts') properly and before localize. I 
    have checked this is working fine. Please check your code should be look like below.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'everstrap-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/assets/js/everstrap_scripts.js' );
        //}

        $script_data_array = array(
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'load_more_posts' ),
        );

wp_localize_script( 'storefront-homepage', 'ajaxobj', $script_data_array );
```

After that add check it in js code using console.log. Like below

```
window.EStrap = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
'use strict';

console.log('ajaxobj.security' + ajaxobj.security);
})(window, document, jQuery);
```